# Can't connect to any host on local network but can connect to everything in internet

Tags: networking, windows-10

I have a windows 10 laptop from my company that is in the company domain and where I'm local admin. 
When I connect the laptop to my home network I can connect to anything on the internet (http/ftp/ssh/etc) but, even if I can ping my home machines from the laptop, I can't connect to them or see their shares. I also can't print to my network printer.
Any ideas of what is blocking this? 
Is there a network monitor that I can see where connections are blocked?

Comment: It would be very helpful if instead of telling us that you "can't" do something you told us precisely how you were trying to do it and precisely what went wrong when you tried it.

Answer (score 1):

Set up regular folder sharing. Home Group is gone, SMBv1 is gone, and Browsing is unreliable also.

The following instructions enable folder sharing between two Windows 10 Machines

1. Make sure Network Discovery and File / Print Sharing are enabled on both computers
2. Make sure password protected sharing is enabled both computers.
3. If you wish to share by computer name instead of IP address, put an entry in the HOSTS file of the computer you are connecting from with the name and IP address of the main computer.
4. Make sure both computers are in the same WORKGROUP and make sure Wireless connections are Private, not Public.
5. This next step depends on computer user names and passwords. If both computers use the same username and password, you can skip this step, restart both and test.

If the user names are different, do the following. Make a username on Main that is a user name and password of the computer you are connecting from. Use this for permissions on the folders on Main you wish to share. It is normally quite difficult to share USER folders because Home Group was removed - security concerns. Use a neutral folder for sharing.

Again after all the above changes restart and test.

On the computer you are connecting from, open a command prompt and type:

NET USE X: \nameofothercomputer\folder

Press enter and then authenticate with the user name and password credentials.

Comment: when I try net use command it returns error 53. They can't be in the same workgroup because my company laptop is in a domain and my home computers aren't. when I try to ssh to my linux machine it says it can't connect.

Comment: Check this Microsoft Answer here. The error is network path not found.  Could be Firewall, the folder you are trying to map to, and indeed, some of the same items as I suggested you work through above. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-networking/system-error-53-has-occurred-the-network-path-was/9511bbd8-ca11-4c1e-8d85-f7e8ce7e0fb9

Comment: Also, even though one machine is a domain machine, you can still connect to the others with a user name and password set up on one machine that others will connect to.

Comment: that doesn't explain why I can't SSH or HTTP to my linux server that is in the same network.

Comment: The connection material above relates to Windows Machines (check your Windows machines) but does not relate to Linux machines

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem.
In the route table there was no entry for 192.168.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 so every packet was sent to the gateway, and somehow it couldn't route correctly the packets!